# Does ALSA buffer size have a hardware-defined upper limit?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, mp3, alsa

I have a Raspberry Pi with an i2s MEMS mic attached. I'm recording audio from it, using the SOX library, and trying to increase my ALSA buffer_size.

My ALSA buffer_size is currently 65536, but I want to increase this. Is there any theoretical limit to the buffer size? How large can it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical limit is 2^32 frames. But the practical limit is whatever your hardware actually supports.

To read the current maximum buffer size, call `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size_max()` ("current" because it might be constrained by other hardware parameters, such as the sample rate or number of channels).